# regular-expression (JAVA)

Tags: java

I had made this Regular Expression for checking the User Full name. but it is accepting the digits and special characters also at the last of the username up to the once place.

cases:

1. Shivkant Dohaliya  - TRUE
2. Shivkant Dohaliya1 - TRUE
3. Shivkant Dohaliya@ - TRUE
4. Shivkant Dohaliya!1- FALSE
5. Shivkant Dohaliya1#- FALSE

   ```
   public void usern()
   {                   
       username="^([a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z]+)$";                 
       pattern=Pattern.compile(username);                                     
       matcher=pattern.matcher(e1.getUname());
       if(matcher.matches()) {                 
          e1.textField1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
       } else {
           e1.textField1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
       }
   }
   ```

I want that it should show RED border for cases 2 and 3 also.

Comment: it might be better that you escape space character

Comment: Your bug must be elsewhere because I have just tested it and it works as expected only #1 returns true

Comment: Your pattern should be a private static final field

Comment: Note that you pattern will return true for the string  "My name is Jim Jones Smith"

Comment: @NicolasFilotto yeah you are right i just checked that but when i am using this in GUI its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use this pattern instead:

```
username="^((?:[a-Z][a-Z]+))(\s)((?:[a-Z][a-Z]+))$";
```

or

```
username="^(\w+)(\s)(\w+)$";
```

For testing only two words separated by space..

Comment: Can you explain your answer, especially the first complicated regex?

Comment: You may also want to fix the syntax errors and escape the backslashes.